# Not able to access spotify Get Followed Artists

Tags: java, spotify-app

I am very new into this. Tried to get data from spotify. So tried the what they are provide but its not working. Getting bad request and in response its showing

```
{
    "error": {
        "status": 400,
        "message": "Client credentials authentication not allowed"
    }
}
```

URL : https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/following?type=artist (Get URL)
Provided Bearer token.

[image: FYI]

Also I want to understand that how can I pass user id here as if I need to get data for particular user.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Client Credential flow is not allowed to access [user specific information](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/). Use a different auth flow. https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (and messing around a bit), I found that the flow should look something like this:

1. Make a request to the `/authorize` endpoint with query params: `cliend_id`, `redirect_uri`, `response_type` and `scopes` (if you're just testing to get a token, use `response_type: token`)
2. You will be asked to log in and authorize the scopes (in this case it should be the scope allowing the client to read the user's artists)
3. In the redirect uri, there will be a token that you can use for the request

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/scopes/